# Zero padding in front using Numeral.js and Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, numeral.js

I'm trying to build a basic Aurelia app.

Suppose I got a data where id = 1.

I can't seem to find a way to have 2 leading zero padding to my id using Numeral.js (http://numeraljs.com/).

I have this code:

```
<span>#${book.number | numberFormat:'000'}</span>
```

I was expecting an output like:

```
#001
```

but all I got was just

```
1
```

Ideally, it should go:

```
#001
#002
#003
...
#023
#024
#025
...
#135
#136
#137
etc
```

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stevies on Aurelia Gitter,

The solution is in the formatter class, we can go:

```
import numeral from 'numeral';

export class NumberFormatValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    var output = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {minimumIntegerDigits: 3, useGrouping: false}).format(value);
    return output;
  }
}
```